# Wamp server not showing css

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

I have created two divs in a .css file and then I have linked that .css file in a php header file like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/headercss.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="default">

</head>


<body bgcolor="#F0F0F0">

<div class="div_menu">
<h1> asdasd </h1>
</div>

<div class="div_main">
```

and here's the css file

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */


.div_menu{
background-image:url('table_header_options.jpg');
width:70%;
margin:auto;
height:50px;
}

.div_main{
background-color:#FFF;
margin:auto;
width:69.75%;
height:800px;
margin-top:15px;

border-width:1px;
border-style:solid;
border-bottom-color:#ddd;
border-right-color:#ddd;
border-top-color:#aaa;
border-left-color:#aaa;
border-radius:10px;
-moz-border-radius:10px;
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
-moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
-webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
}
```

I am sure that there is nothing going wrong with the directories because everythings going fine when I run the php file simply using google chrome but when I try to open it from localhost through wamp server everything disappears except the h1 tag.

Any help will be highly appreciated !

Comment: open developer tools and reload, click network tab and look for the css file, ensure it (and all related resources) returns HTTP 200

Comment: What do you mean with 'works fine in chrome, but not from localhost'? Are you testing online in a live enviroment or are you using some different program to access your localhost?

Comment: testing online but what i mean is no css effects are showing up through localhost but when i simply right click and open the php file with google chrome then everything appears correct . why  ?

Comment: I didn't say it will work, I said `ensure it returns HTTP 200`. What do you get there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that the css is called from the correct relative postition.

Since this is a PHP header file I assume you're calling it from various places (like `/`, `/about`, `/otherfolder`, etc).

The problem is that your current code will look for the css folder inside the *current* folder, not the top folder where it actually is.

Thus:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/headercss.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="default">`

Notice the absolute positioning of `/css/headercss.css` - the `/` at the front means "from the top".

EDIT: Turns out OP is using CodeIgniter and should resubmit his question tagged as such.

Comment: everythings working fine when i simply open with google chrome but with localhost css disappears

Comment: Open up the developer console and take a look at the return code for the css file - pay attention to where the GET call is trying to find it (relative to where it actually is).

Comment: from where should i open developer console ?

Comment: if the problem is with the directories then why everythings going fine when opening with google chrome?

Comment: Because in chrome you're not parsing the PHP - It's rendering as HTML. Try putting <?php echo('hello') ?> in there and open it in chrome - it won't show up. Run it in localhost and you'll see "hello" printed.

Comment: I know that, and for now you can see that there is no php code in my document

Comment: also, the css folder is in the same folder where the php file is

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15031/discussion-between-saaram-and-erty)

Comment: couldn't you also use `../` to signify one folder up?

Answer (score 0):

actually after you transfered all of it to your wampserver your images changes it's location therefore you need to change the backgroung-image:url('') of all your div something that you had designed. Then VIOLA it will appear

Answer (score 0):

Use port 80 for apache server in wamp